# How can I 'pan out' (make screen bytes smaller) of the console screen to render 2d pyramids larger?

Tags: c++, oop, geometry, codeblocks, shapes

**I am using Windows 10 with code blocks to compile my code.**

I wonder WHY you want to do that. This seems to be a typical homework assignment problem for practising loops and logic. That usually is restricted to numbers easily fitting on a console. Could you elaborate what causes the need to go beyond say a size of 30? – Yunnosch 10 hours ago

@Yunnosch For pure hypothetical and experimental reasons. I essentially have a dream I could write a program that renders massive 2d pyramids on a console screen, and maybe create some game out of it. I was hoping I could figure out a way to 'pan out' of the console screen thus making the screen bytes smaller. Somebody has to know more than me, and can lead me in the right direction to accomplishing this '2d pyramid rendering' program. Thanks in advance! – Fibonacci 3 mins ago

My goal is to be able to render massive pyramid structures onto a console output screen. The code here simply asks for a number of rows and prints out a pyramid. ex. drawPyramid(50);

```
#include <iostream> // include iostream
using namespace std; // include std


// Draw pyramid function here
 void drawPyramid(int rows)
{
    // initializes space and creates for loop to keep track of rows, I and k
    int space;
    for(int i = 1, k = 0; i <= rows; ++i, k=0)
    {
        // draws spaces required
        for(space = 1; space <= rows-i; ++space)
        {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        // draws matter
        while(k != 2*i-1)
        {
            cout << "* ";
            ++k;
        }
        //prints new line based on rows
        cout << endl;
    }
}


//driver program
int main()
{
    bool fTrue = false;

    // loops until user presses '0'
    while(!fTrue)
    {
        cout << "Press (0) to quit...\n";
        int i,rows;
        cout << "Enter number of rows: \n";
        cin >> rows;
        drawPyramid(rows); // draw function called
        if(rows == 0)
        {
            fTrue = true;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 
[image: drawPyramidOutput]

While the program works great I'd like to be able to pass in bigger values such as drawPyramid(500); or drawPyramid(1000); anything above the value 50 produces results like so.

Results: 
[image: badPyramidOutput]

Hopefully you can understand what I am trying to ask. I want to be able to 'pan out' and move the asterisks closer together so that I can pass in larger input values into the drawPyramid() function... Thanks in advance!

**I am using Windows 10 with code blocks to compile my code.**

Comment: In order to to control the console like this you'd need some kind of interface to communicate with the OS. What OS are you using?

Comment: can you lower the font of your terminal ?

Comment: Your terminal is *Line-Wrapping*, redirect the output to a file, e.g. `./drawpyramid > pyramidfile` (then open `pyramidfile` and make sure *Line-Wrapping* is OFF)

Comment: @John I am using windows 10 codeblocks… I know this is possible I just need to be led to the right resources. Sam please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex

Comment: The windows console window has an explicit width, you can increase it in the window properties

Comment: I wonder WHY you want to do that. This seems to be a typical homework assignment problem for practising loops and logic. That usually is restricted to numbers easily fitting on a console. Could you elaborate what causes the need to go beyond say a size of 30?

Comment: @Yunnosch For pure hypothetical and experimental reasons. I essentially have a dream I could write a program that renders massive 2d pyramids on a console screen, and maybe create some game out of it. I was hoping I could figure out a way to 'pan out' of the console screen thus making the screen bytes smaller. Somebody has to know more than me, and can lead me in the right direction to accomplishing this '2d pyramid rendering' program. Thanks in advance!